# How to remove prefix value from route:resource in laravel?

Tags: url, routes, laravel-5, prefix

I am creating an application in laravel 5.2.

I have used route:resource like this in my routes.php
`Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');` now this is how it looks like in the url `http://project.app:8000/users/ryan`

I am trying to remove the `users` from the url to look something like this  `http://project.app:8000/ryan`

Is there an easy way to do this and still works the same way it did before?
Please somebody help, Thanks!

Comment: What is ryan in your route, Is it a parameter?

Comment: `ryan` is a name of a user. there will be many users in the applications. I am building a forum  where all the users will have their own profile page. I want to give them a friendly url thats why instead of `/users/ryan` i want just `ryan` thats the `slug` that is taken from each registered users `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following route:

```
Route::get('/{name?}', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UsersController@profile'));
```

The optional parameter works for you.

I'm using same in my web http://example.com/samrow

Put this route after all routs :)

Comment: What a brilliant solution! Thank you very much :)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. then other get help from this